# how to extract JSON object data from laravel API?

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

I want to extract JSON data from laravel using JQUERY but the result is always undefined.

this is the json code I've got:

```
{"data":{"id":1,"title":"glove hard","code":"0102","category":"glove"}}
```

and this is the js code:

```
        $('#show').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'example.com/api/product/1',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').text(data.category)
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Why not add something like `console.log(data)` to see what data contains?

Comment: should be `data.data.category`

Comment: Thank you so much Brother Your answer is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Since your code return JSON data is

```
{"data":{"id":1,"title":"glove hard","code":"0102","category":"glove"}}
```

The ajax success function parameter is called data and the first key in the json result is named data, to access the value of category, your code should be

```
   $('#show').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'example.com/api/product/1',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
             //Call the first wrapper key first.
            $('#result').text(data.data.category)
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the $.parseJSON which parse the well formatted json string into js object.
Your success callback will be

```
success: function(data){
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#result').text(obj.data.category)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it even simpler:

```
jQuery('#show')
.click(function() {
    jQuery
    .getJSON('example.com/api/product/1')
    .done(function(data) {
        jQuery('#result').text(data.data.category);
    }
});
```